# RemoteConnect yields missing library error

Tags: remote-access, installation

**Problem:** In Linux, I recently upgraded from Wolfram Desktop 12.0 to Wolfram Desktop 12.1.  When I attempt to use SSH functionality

```
RemoteConnect["192.168.0.123", "username", "password"]
```

I get:

[image]

or in text form:

```
LibraryFunction: The library /nix/store/g4azpz4jl9bh0x600flp8pdsp6mb027n-wolfram-desktop-12.1 .0/libexec/Mathematica/SystemFiles/Links/SecureShellLink/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64/libSecureShellLink.so cannot be loaded.
```

**Solution attempt.** When I then check this library via `ldd` I discover the issue:

```
ldd /nix/store/g4azpz4jl9bh0x600flp8pdsp6mb027n-wolfram-desktop-12.1.0/libexec/Mathematica/SystemFiles/Links/SecureShellLink/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64/libSecureShellLink.so | grep "not found"
```

yields

```
    libssl.so.1.1 => not found
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found
```

If I add

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/openssl/lib ldd /nix/store/g4azpz4jl9bh0x600flp8pdsp6mb027n-wolfram-desktop-12.1.0/libexec/Mathematica/SystemFiles/Links/SecureShellLink/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64/libSecureShellLink.so | grep "not found"
```

then the problem goes away; however, if launch `wolframdesktop` via

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/openssl/lib wolframdesktop
```

and then try to run `RemoteConnect`, then I get the same, original error! Does anyone have any suggestions on how to restore SSH functionality in Wolfram?